# scriptaculous Builder equivalent in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, scriptaculous

I like the scriptaculous [Builder](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/builder/) syntax to create DOM elements. 
Is there something similar in jQuery?

I'd prefer not to use something like

```
$("<div><p>Hello</p></div>").appendTo("body")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DOMBrew](https://github.com/glebm/DOMBrew) is an option http://jsperf.com/jquery-dom-vs-custom-dom/4

```
var $b = DOMBrew;

$("#thetable").append($b('tr#row-of-one').append(
  $b('td.red').append(
    $b('ul').append(
      $b('li.lists', 'one'),
      $b('li', 'two')
    )
  ),
  $b('td.blue').append(
    $b('p', 'This is a bunch of text that is right here.')
  ),

  $b('td.orange').append(
    $b('table#smallertable').append(
      $b('thead').append(
        $b('tr').append(
          $b('th', { colspan: 2, text: 'this is small' })
        )
      ),
      $b('tbody').append(
        $b('tr').append(
          $b('td', 'Go win.'),
          $b('td', 'Go fight.')
        )
      )
    )    
  ),

  $b('td.purple').append($b('#divided', 'Content'))
).dom());
```

Comment: But I still must say, this is not a nice way the build HTML. I work with client side templates, like Google closure templates, which is way faster and easier on the eye for understanding what the actual HTML structure is https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/helloworld_js

Comment: do you have server side javascript support as well?

Comment: Google Closure templates does. It can generate the HTML with both JS (client) and Java (server) from the same template https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/helloworld_java